# How to change the appearance of Kivy Settings pane

Tags: python, json, user-interface, kivy

I have been using Kivy for a few weeks now and I really like the built in settings pane. I have used this to allow users to specify some file paths ans toggle settings. This all works fine, but I have been unable to change to appearance of this screen. There are two main things I want to modify.

First off I want to change the color of the text in the settings 'Close' button. I have modified the window colors by changing the default theme, but I don't know how to access the close button from my App Class. Looking the source code I can see the button's name is close_button which is a child of menu, but I can't seem to access it.

In addition to change the text colors in settings, I would like to modify the layout so that long paths will wrap down to two lines. I build the content of the settings page using a json file (except shown below) and I can't seem to figure out how to specify height and text_size for these items.

```
 {'type': 'title',
 'title': 'Input Files:'},
{'type': 'path',
 'title': '1st file path',
 'desc': 'use the file browser to select your file',
 'section': 'paths',
 'key': 'path1'},
  ....
```

Any advice that will help me modify the appearance of my settings page would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The panel isn't currently very configurable without modifying its kv rules directly (though this is an option). You could open a feature request about it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @inclement Can you point me towards where i would find the kv rules that control this? I don't mind having separate builds for separate apps, so this would be a decent short term solution.

Comment: In kivy they're in kivy/data/style.kv . You can replace a rule entirely in your own kv file with `<-WidgetName>`, in which case all previously defined kv won't be applied but this rule will.

Comment: Thanks @inclement, worked great.